# Get Accounts information using AccountManager

Tags: android

I have used AccountManager for my application to prefill the email address. But I am not able to get the email address. Why ??

**Here is my code**

```
String emailAddress = null;
Account[] accounts = AccountManager.get(getApplicationContext()).getAccounts();
for(Account acc : accounts) {
    if(acc.type.equals("com.google")) {
        emailAddress = acc.name;
        break;
    }
}
```

But the emailAddress field get the string as "hidden due to security". I have also given the permission as :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
```

Can anyone will help me out for this ??

Comment: Have you configured google account on your device/emulator?

Comment: Yes..  I have configured...

Comment: Can you post the class in which you are executing your code?

Comment: @Govind Please check my answer . I hope it will helps you .Happy coding

Answer (score 2):

Add this `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />`

For better information you may visits [Account-manager](https://www.finalconcept.com.au/article/view/android-account-manager-step-by-step-2),[Google AccountManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html), [google-oauth-on-android-using](http://blog.tomtasche.at/2013/05/google-oauth-on-android-using.html) And [android-account-manager-part-i](http://www.jiahaoliuliu.com/2012/05/android-account-manager-part-i.html).

For best Demo

### [How to get all registered email accounts in Android](http://javatechig.com/android/how-to-get-all-registered-email-accounts-in-android)

Comment: Added the permission. but then also its not working... When I use account.name, it says "hidden due to security".